# Change or not field focus after autofill next fields

Tags: forms, input-focus, autofill

There is a form with following fields in following order:

Zip City State Phone

When user enter zip code fields city and state got auto populated based on zip code user entered.

The question is it a good idea to move field focus from zip to phone field after autocomplete happened or no? Basically user enter zip code, next fields got autopopulated and the focus already on phone field. So less actions from user.

Is there any examples how similar functionality done in other websites?

Comment: Lots of other examples exist. Most common scheme seems to be enter zip code, then populate City/State automagically, where City/State are read-only fields. In UK, we use postcode and house name/number, from which complete address can be deduced. Only enable City/State fields for edit, if the Zip Code is ambiguous.

Comment: @SteveJones the question is about should i change input focus from zip code field to phone field automatically or not, and why :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I answered, by referring to the numerous other cases that exist. This is a solved problem and has been for a long time.

Comment: @SteveJones i dont see anything about moving input focus in your answer...

Comment: If you read what I said, it is obvious that after the Zip Code you go to the phone number, as the City & State fields are read-only. I wouldn't recommend moving focus automatically, as that is annoying. So, just two fields to edit: Zip Code & Phone, in addition to two read-only fields for City & State which can be deduced once you have a valid Zip Code.

Comment: @SteveJones My question was exactly about moving focus automatically, probably i made it unclear. Yes, im afraid that it might be confusing on one hand but on other it will make user to do less actions

Comment: I was attempting to answer this question "Is there any examples how similar functionality done in other websites?" in your original post. In general, moving the focus automatically is a bad idea, IMHO, YMMV.

Comment: @SteveJones but for example in stripe when completing credit card info focus moves automatically to next field when current one is filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving focus automatically is not a good idea. User may have done a mistake (e.g. swapped two digits by mistake, 37 instead of 73) and wants to modify it. When focus is automatically moved, user will press a couple of keys (like "Backspace", "7", "3" to change 37 to 73). But if the focus is in another field, it has two problems: this may initiate validation in another field (which will be misleading) and user will be irritated, because he has to switch focus back. He will loose time.

You can prefill in the next fields whatever you want, but it is better to keep the focus in the current field, not move it automatically.